# The change of the difference between solutions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Consider the following equation for a fixed $\lambda \gt0$: $$x\lambda^3\sqrt{x}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2\lambda^4}{2}\right) = C, \ \ \ C\gt0$$ I think the equation doesn't have a closed form solution. If we consider, $$f(x)= x\lambda^3\sqrt{x}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2\lambda^4}{2}\right)$$ then by taking derivative it can be seen that $f(x)$ has a global maxima at $x^*=\frac{\sqrt{3/2}}{\lambda}$. This means geometrically that we are intersecting a Gaussian-like function $y=f(x)$ with $y=C$ for every $\lambda$. So there are two solutions which are $x_1\lt x^*$ and $x_2>x^*$. Define the difference between these solutions as $d=x_2-x_1$. I want to show that if $\lambda_1\lt \lambda_2$ then $d_1\gt d_2$. In words, if we increase the parameter $\lambda$ then the difference between solutions decrease. I tried to show that $x_1\lt x_1'$ but it didn't work. By $x_1'$, I mean the smaller solution for the case $\lambda=\lambda_2$. Is it possible to use the derivative for proving the statement somehow? Maybe we can differentiate with respect to $\lambda$ and then argue about the solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the roots of this equation have a very simple dependence on $\lambda$ that can be extracted analytically. First, we restrict $\lambda>0$ so that this equation stays within the real numbers. Then we raise both sides to the $4/3$-th power:

$$x^2 e^{-\frac{2x^2\lambda^4}{3}}=C^{4/3}/\lambda^4$$

Now set $y=-\frac{2x^2\lambda^4}{3}$ and obtain the equivalent equation

$$ye^y=-\frac{2C^{4/3}}{3}$$

The explicit dependence on $\lambda$ has disappeared! The last equation written has two negative solutions $0>y_1(C)> y_2(C)$ that coincidentally can be written in terms of the branches of the Lambert-W function

$$y_1(C)=W_0\left(-\frac{2C^{4/3}}{3}\right)~~,~~ y_2(C)=W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2C^{4/3}}{3}\right)$$

However, we don't need this analytical result to extract the property that we need: the two solutions to the original equation can now be written (by solving for $x$)

$$x_{1,2}(\lambda,C)=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\sqrt{-\frac{3}{2}y_{1,2}(C)}$$

which shows that $d=x_2-x_1\propto \lambda^{-2}$ and hence decreasing in that variable for every $C< (3/2e)^{3/4}$. When $C=(3/2e)^{3/4}$ the two roots of the equation coincide into a double root (this is the maximum of the function $f(x)$) and therefore $d=0$ and is constant in $\lambda.$ For any other value of $C$, we cannot define the root functions unless we cross into the complex plane, as usual. However the functional dependence of the roots on $\lambda$ should persist after complexification as well.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on the $d=x_2-x_1\propto \lambda^{-2}$ part? Suppose that for $\lambda_1$ we have $x_2 - x_1 = \frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}\sqrt{-\frac{3}{2}y_2} - \frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}\sqrt{-\frac{3}{2}y_1}$. Now for $\lambda_2 \gt \lambda_1$ we have  $x_2' - x_1' =\frac{1}{\lambda_2^2}\sqrt{-\frac{3}{2}y_2'} - \frac{1}{\lambda_2^2}\sqrt{-\frac{3}{2}y_1'}$. How it can be proved that $x_2'-x_1' \lt x_2 - x_1$?

Comment: I think there should be a connection between $y_1$ and $y_1'$ (and similarly $y_2$ and $y_2'$). By intuition, it's clear that $x_1 \lt x_1'$ and $x_2 \gt x_2'$ but I don't see how it can be proved formally.

Comment: This is an easy exercise, you just need to prove $a/x^2$ is a decreasing function of x for positive x. You can take a derivative and show it's negative, or use algebraic manipulations on the definition of monotonicity to prove it. By the way $y_1, y_2$ don't depend on $\lambda$ so they can be treated as constants and that's why the exercise is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same as @DinosaurEgg

$$x\lambda^3\sqrt{x}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2\lambda^4}{2}\right) = C$$ the two solutions are
$$x_1=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\frac {1}{\lambda^2}  \sqrt{-W_0\left(-\frac{2 }{3}C^{4/3}\right)}\quad\quad x_2=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\frac {1}{\lambda^2}  \sqrt{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2 }{3}C^{4/3}\right)}$$

which, in the real domain, exist if
$$-\frac{2 }{3}C^{4/3} \geq -\frac 1 e \quad \implies \quad C \leq \left(\frac{3}{2 e}\right)^{3/4}$$

Using $k=-\frac{2 }{3}C^{4/3}$

$$\frac {d(x_2-x_1)}{dC}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\,\frac{1}{C \lambda ^2}   \left(\frac{\sqrt{-W_{-1}(k)}}{1+W_{-1}(k)}-\frac{\sqrt{-W_{0}(k)}}{1+W_{0}(k)}\right)$$

Using series expansion around $k=-\frac 1e$, a quite good approximation is

$$F(k)=\frac{\sqrt{-W_{-1}(k)}}{1+W_{-1}(k)}-\frac{\sqrt{-W_{0}(k)}}{1+W_{0}(k)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, t^{2n-1} \quad \text{where}\quad t=\sqrt{\frac {e k +1} 2 }$$ the first coefficient being
$$\left\{-1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{10}{27},\frac{2342}{6075},\frac{63134
   }{127575},-\frac{817162555843}{339492384000},\cdots\right\}$$
You can easily check that, for $0\leq t \leq \frac 12$ and any level of expansion, $F(k)$ is always negative.